Find catch blocks that return optional empty
I'm using pcregrep to find catch blocks in my java project files that return Optional.empty()
pcregrep -M 'catch.+{(\n|.)+return\s+Optional.empty()}'
This gives
pcregrep: Check your regex for nested unlimited loops.

How can I improve my regular expression to avoid this?

https://regex101.com/ may help you.
